# Referring to int as string in mysql query

Tags: mysql, database

While working with MySQL database I did some queries which made me astonished !
Let suppose a small table with ID as `int` and name as `varchar` and when I made an update query based on ID just like this (using C#):

```
MySqlCommand comm = new MySqlCommand("UPDATE database.table SET Name=@name WHERE id=@id", sqlconn);
comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", textbox1.text);
comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", textbox2.text);
comm.ExecuteNonQuery();
sqlconn.Close();
```

And that did work completely correct, so isn't a matter if ID passed to database as `int` or even as `string`, what is going on could someone please explain to  me ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MySQL is a "do what I mean" sort of database and will automatically convert types as required.

Most of the time this is a good thing, it means you don't have to fuss with casting, but sometimes it can lead to ambiguity and odd errors when it does things without you knowing, like truncating data silently.

Comment: Wow, really magnificent !
so no worry to convert all IDs in my code from string to int :)